# When to write asynchronous logs

Tags: c++, logging, asynchronous

I'm trying to write an asynchronous logging class and can't decide on when to write the logs to the file.

Right now, I'm thinking of storing all the logs in a vector and then sort them by their timestamps.

The problem is when should I write the logs to a file? If I wait for N logs before writing to disk, I might miss a log entry or one might be written to the log out of sequence if we already reached N logs in the vector.

I was thinking of maybe using a timer of some sort but I'm not sure if that would be any better.

I would appreciate any ideas, thanks.

Comment: You probably want to write them to the file out-of-order, and fix that in the tools that read the log. For example make sure the log format is such that the lines can be lexicographically sorted to put them into data order, by putting a big-endian datestamp at the start of the line: 20120912T0001Z. I expect that by definition of "asynchronous", you can never be absolutely certain that there isn't a log message dated in early 1970 about to land on you, and hence you can never write anything to file with absolute certainty.

Comment: Also, the joking answer is that you should always commit the log to file just *before* the program crashes :-)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @Steve. If we don't care about the order, should I still buffer the logs? And LOL, I would do that if I could guarantee that the logger didn't crash with the program ;)

Comment: Well, in practice you can get the file in the right order 90-mumble percent of the time by buffering 2N messages, and writing out N of them (the oldest half) when the buffer fills. There's probably a trade-off between logging promptly, making the file readable by a human without sorting, and lulling a human reader into a false sense of security that they don't need to sort.

Comment: Hm. How do I choose an appropriate buffer size for something like this? Is it arbitrary?

Comment: I think so. The buffer size you want is, "the max number of messages that occur between a message that arrives promptly, and a message dated just before it that arrives late". It's really up to the users of your logger (and the scheduler) 
what that number is.

Comment: Just occurred to me that one thing you could do is put a warning in the log (or somewhere else) when messages are written out of order. You know this because you can easily remember what the max. date written so far is, and flag the log as out-of-order if you ever write one smaller.

Comment: I would insist you have the option to turn all buffering OFF.  If there is a crash you will probably not get the events leading up to the crash if the messages are buffered.  That information could be critical in determining the cause of the crash.  I would use a prebuilt logger like:  http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Comment: @Steve: true, although the fact that the logging is in some sense "asynchronous" probably already means that it's not as good a crash log as you might hope. Even if you don't buffer at this level, the fact that messages can arrive out of order means that you can lose some if you crash. It might be that instead of / as well as an option to disable the buffer, there should be an option to make the log synchronous. There are other purposes for logs than debugging crashes, though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment about writing them out of order with no buffering (or explicit flushes).  However, if you want to write them in-order, I would have a separate thread that manages writing.  You would define a specific lag amount (in seconds, presumably) that you can reasonably guarantee will cover any late-arrivals.

So in a very basic sense you'd have a thread function something like:

```
time_t writeDelay = 10;  // 10 seconds

for(;;)
{
    // Sleep for a second
    //[OS-specific code here]

    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    WriteLogEntriesUpTo(now - writeDelay);
}
```

Problem here is that sorting your log entries into a vector might introduce a lot of overhead into your logger if you don't do it right.  At the very least use a `deque` so you can pop entries off the front easily.  If I was to do this, I'd probably go down the path of having a large buffer (effectively a memory pool) for my log strings and simple records in my queue.  Something with a timestamp and a pointer would make it easy to sort.

```
struct LogEntry {
    time_t timestamp;
    char *message;
};
```

Instead of putting these in a `deque` I'd implement some kind of ordered list (again, memory-pooled).  To make all this fast would be quite fiddly.  The more you think about it, the more it makes sense to just write out-of-order.

Comment: With care, you can sort a circular buffer taking account of the fact that it wraps around at the end -- access the indexes after taking a modulus, basically. In C++ this probably means writing a suitable iterator. Then adding at the end and removing from the start are fast *without* being fiddly, it's just the sort (or rather, the iterator) that's fiddly. `deque` is good too.

Comment: Yeah one way or another it amounts to being fiddly.  What you could have is a circular queue representing the number of seconds old a log message is.  Each element in the queue is a vector.  When you add a log item, you push it into the correct vector.  Then you get ordered inserts without searching or sorting (unless you have sub-second timestamps).  There's a couple of tricky bits in this approach, but there are simple solutions to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with asynchronous logging I would suggest using a thread-safe queue to pump all messages with a time-stamp to a logging thread worker. The logging worker can then process all messages in a block as they appear on the queue.

This thread-safe queue abstraction allows for you to set the buffer size or leave it unrestricted (you can message the thread if the queue/buffer fills via condition variable), log from many threads simultaneously, and process logs even after an error occurs if you wrap the main thread in a try catch loop that waits for the logger to finish before exiting (ok it won't help with a segfaults, but it still helps with most errors). Additionally you can punt messages to the logger and move on in the main program thread without needing to wait on any IO operations (potentially a huge win in execution time). It's also not difficult to implement. A queue has very limited API so you're interaction with the data structure can just wrap a list with some scoped locking.

You pay a small price for this implementation -- namely locking prices. But if you need to add any other multi-threading you don't have to rebuild your logger and by offloading the IO to another thread you'll probably go faster than a single threaded logger.

If you have messages that come out of order, you have two options. Do log sorting on the log worker side of the queue (keep a local buffer for the worker to keep older messages). Or change the implementation of the log queue to be a priority queue using the timestamp to order the messages and pay a little higher price on insert. The latter is probably easier to implement but pays a higher synchronization price.

I've used this strategy in C++ using Boost threads and it works quite well. I can crash and still get logs from right before the crash and as I branch work into various threads for easily parallelizable work I just use the same log abstraction everywhere for easy tracking of event ordering.